# How to use a function to open a link in html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a website thats going to work like an online advent calendar; I want to be able to make sure that a link wont open until the correct day. Heres what I have so far:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,90,150" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" alt="1" target="_blank" onClick="return canOpen(this)">

  <script>
    function canOpen(isTrue) {
      var isOpen = new Date("Dec "+isTrue+", 2020 00:00:00").getTime();
      var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
      var timeDifference = isOpen - currentTime;

      if (timeDifference > 0) {
        <! Go to link>
      }
      else {
        <! Show popup "You can't open this yet!>
      }
  }
  </script>
```

How could I make it so that you can go to the link if it is past the date in question, and how would I get the value of alt out of the link and into the script?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window)

Comment: Also - the first result on google when you search for [open link in js](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to get attribute alt as event date for check in script.
Then check if the current date passed event date, redirect by change site's `location`, or do anything else you like otherwise, if the element has redirect as default behavior (like `a` tag), you will need `return false;` to prevent default behavior.

```js
function canOpen(element) {
  var isOpen = new Date("Dec "+element.getAttribute("alt")+", 2020 00:00:00").getTime();
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  var timeDifference = isOpen - currentTime;

  if (timeDifference > 0) {
    window.location.href = element.getAttribute("href");
  } else {
    alert("Not yet!");
    // return false; // for `a` tag
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created two functions, one to set the date, and one to check if the link can open. If the release date has passed, the `href` of the link changes from "#" to the Youtube link. The date updates every second with `setInterval`.

[Example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omartheman949/ovqd0Ljr/)

Also, did I just get RickRolled?

```
  <a id="premiere-link" href="#">Youtube Link</a>

  <script>
    // setInterval(canOpen, 1000);
    let month, day, year, time;
    const link = document.getElementById('premiere-link');
    setDate(); //set date immediatly on page load
    setInterval(setDate, 1000); //update date every second
    function setDate() {
      var dateObj = new Date();
      month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
      day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
      year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
      time = dateObj.getTime();
    }
    function canOpen(month, day){
      //set month and day for release
      if (month >= 11 && day >= 1) {
        alert('You just got RickRolled')
        link.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ');
      } else {
        link.setAttribute('href', '#');
        alert('You have to wait to get RickRolled')
      }
    }
    link.onclick = () => {canOpen(month, day)};
  </script>
```